# Multiple argument error when passing Multi-Value Parameter from SSRS to UDF

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I found a UDF online that splits a comma delimited string for the purpose of passing a multi-value parameter to it from SSRS. The UDF takes 1 argument which is data type VARCHAR(MAX).

The UDF works great when I test it and send a string with single quotes e.g '001,002,003' but from what I understand SSRS is passing 001,002,003 without the single quotes. When this is passed to the UDF I get the error that too many arguments were passed. I get this both in testing in SQL Server Management Studio and SSRS.

I'm trying to figure out how I can add the single quotes prior to sending the parameter to the UDF in SSRS. I've tried calling the UDF and setting the variable passed to '' + @MyVar + '' in the DECLARE statement as well as the argument for the UDF. I've also tried creating another variable with 2 single quotes and concatenating the variables e.g. @Quote + @MyVar + @Quote. So far nothing is working.

Here's the UDF I'm using:

```
`CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitQuotedString] (@String varchar(max))
RETURNS @Array TABLE (Item varchar(8000))
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE
      @Pos int,
      @End int,
      @TextLength int,
      @Item varchar(8000),
      @Fragment varchar(8000),
      @InQuotes bit
    SET @TextLength = DataLength(@String)

   IF @TextLength = 0 RETURN
   SET @Pos = 1
   SET @InQuotes = 0
   SET @String = @String + ','
   SET @Item = ''
   WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN
      SET @End = CharIndex(',', @String, @Pos)
      IF @End = 0 BREAK
      SET @Fragment = Substring(@String, @Pos, @End - @Pos)
      IF @InQuotes = 1 BEGIN


         SET @InQuotes = PatIndex('%[^'']%', Reverse(@Fragment) + 'x') % 2
         SET @Item = @Item + ',' + Replace(Left(@Fragment, DataLength(@Fragment) - 1 + @InQuotes), '''''', '''')
      END

      ELSE BEGIN
         IF @Fragment LIKE '''%' BEGIN
            SET @InQuotes = 1
            SET @Item = Replace(Substring(@Fragment, 1 + @InQuotes, 8000), '''''', '''')
         END
         ELSE BEGIN
            SET @Item = @Fragment
         END
      END

      IF @InQuotes = 0 BEGIN
         INSERT @Array (Item) VALUES (@Item)
         SET @Item = ''
      END
      SET @Pos = @End + 1
   END

   RETURN
END
`
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the UDF was the issue. I found modified and used another UDF and it's working after adding =JOIN(Parameters!MyVar.Value, ",") to the "Parameters" tab of my dataset in SSRS. Here's the function I used:

```
create function Split ( 
@StringToSplit varchar(2048),
@Separator varchar(128))
returns table as return
with indices as
( 
select 0 S, 1 E
union all
select E, charindex(@Separator, @StringToSplit, E) + len(@Separator) 
from indices
where E > S 
)
select substring(@StringToSplit,S, 
case when E > len(@Separator) then e-s-len(@Separator) else len(@StringToSplit) - s + 1 end) String
,S StartIndex        
from indices where S >0
```